# Dynamically change SVG image color in android

Tags: android, svg, imageview, android-view, svg-filters

I know that using third party library, it is possible to use SVG image in Android.
Library like: [svg-android](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/)

The code to load SVG image is like below:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create a new ImageView
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    // Set the background color to white
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    // Parse the SVG file from the resource
    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);
    // Get a drawable from the parsed SVG and set it as the drawable for the ImageView
    imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
    // Set the ImageView as the content view for the Activity
    setContentView(imageView);
}
```

It's working fine. I'm able to see the image. But now I want to change the color for the svg image at runtime. 
For that I tried the code below as mentioned in the same project description.

```
  // 0xFF9FBF3B is the hex code for the existing Android green, 0xFF1756c9 is the new blue color
    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android, 0xFF9FBF3B, 0xFF1756c9);
```

But with that I am not able to see the change in the color. So I would like to know how it is possible to change the color dynamically in Java file.

Comment: Make sure this color `0xFF9FBF3B` exists in your svg (just open it in a text editor and search for this value). Keep in mind that the color change only happens **when you load the file**, not dynamically. So, just reload the file to apply the color change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got where is the problem. 
The issue is with the color code i am using in svg file. 
Its not exactly **0xFF9FBF3B** but **#9FBF3B**
But during java code you have to write it with ARGB value (e.g. 0xFF9FBF3B).
I have updated it and its work fine now. I can able to change the color of svg file with same code.

Hope this will also help others to identify the actual case while changing the color of the SVG image at runtime.

Comment: I can not change color of this image in imageview https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/android-generalize.appspot.com/o/test.svg?alt=media&token=ea6faaff-0e6c-4f96-9953-185cb496def5 color
have you any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Can you please check @Antlip Dev's answer. That is more accurate.

Comment: Also we have tintColor option in in XML for Imageview. You can try with that as well.

Comment: tint option can change image only which had .xml format and i had .svg format url

Comment: You can also change the SVG image colour dynamically.

Answer (score 40):

I know it's kind of late but I also had this issue and was able to fix this issue using the [setColorFilter(int color, PorterDuff.Mode mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)) method.

Example:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the answer of [Antlip Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33177536/2914140) in **Kotlin**.

```
package com.example.... // Your package.

import android.graphics.PorterDuff
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.annotation.ColorRes
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

fun ImageView.setSvgColor(@ColorRes color: Int) =
    setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
```

Usage:

```
view.your_image.setSvgColor(R.color.gray)
```

Comment: Best to avoid using !! whenever possible, better to do something like context?.let { setSvgColor(it, ... }

Comment: @crobicha, I agree with you. But when you call these methods from `view`, `context != null`.

Comment: @crobicha, thanks for your answer. I simplified the method. Please, see an update.

Answer (score 2):

what @Antlip Dev said is correct, but that method is deprecated now.
This is the updated version:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    drawable.setColorFilter(new BlendModeColorFilter(color, BlendMode.SRC_ATOP));
} else {
   drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: drawableTint to change the color

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(),ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorAccent))