# change programmatically gradient color inside the path tag of vector drawable

Tags: android, vector, drawable

My Vector:

```
<vector android:height="100dp" android:viewportHeight="386.999"
    android:viewportWidth="584.999" android:width="150dp"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:pathData="M21.999,0.125h540c12.428,0 22.5,10.073 22.5,22.5v341.999c0,12.426 -10.072,22.5 -22.5,22.5h-540c-12.426,0 -22.499,-10.074 -22.499,-22.5V22.625C-0.5,10.198 9.573,0.125 21.999,0.125z">
        <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
            <gradient android:endX="502.2204" android:endY="444.1562"
                android:startX="81.7783" android:startY="-56.9072" android:type="linear">
                <item android:color="#FFF2612E" android:offset="0"/>
                <item android:color="#FFF6871F" android:offset="1"/>
            </gradient>
        </aapt:attr>
    </path>

    <path android:fillAlpha="0.1" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M35.5,11.375h512.999c12.426,0 22.5,10.073 22.5,22.5v319.499c0,12.427 -10.074,22.501 -22.5,22.501H35.5c-12.426,0 -22.5,-10.074 -22.5,-22.501V33.875C12.999,21.448 23.073,11.375 35.5,11.375z"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.1" android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="4"/>
</vector>
```

[image]

I want to assign color programmatically for 2 items

```
<item android:color="#FFF2612E" android:offset="0"/>
<item android:color="#FFF6871F" android:offset="1"/>
```

I search over here but didn't find what exactly i want it.
[Dynamically change SVG image color in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626640/dynamically-change-svg-image-color-in-android)

https://medium.com/@emmaguy/dynamically-changing-svg-colours-on-android-b026a99137ad

https://github.com/devendroid/VectorChildFinder

Comment: Why don't you just create another vector file with different color? It should be much easier ^^

Comment: How to achieves the gradient effect by using two vector files @BachVu. I don't think so it will be give the effect like gradient box